# Spring MVC 3 - Need help in resolving the url-pattern issue

Tags: spring-mvc

I am developing an app with spring mvc and here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For serving static content, I added the following line in my admin-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.prasanna.blog.Server" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/"/>
```

I have 5 controllers each mapped to particular url for example  `adminRequests.java` is mapped to `/admin/*`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/*")
public class AdminRequests
```

Then I have methods inside the class mapped to particular urls.

The problem is, I am getting 404 error when the url-pattern in web.xml is mapped as `/` .But when I change the url pattern in web.xml to `/app` or any other , my `index.html` is served without any issues.

I am not sure where the problem is. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

When you map Url pattern / to Spring's Dispatcher Servlet, all the request to your application is forwarded to Dispatcher Servlet. Although in this case you defined the static resources using `<mvc:resources>` tag, but your index.html is not resolved properly because it is not rendered as /resources/index.html but /index.html.

I would suggest you to add one more `<servlet-mapping>` in your web.xml before spring's `<servlet-mapping>`. For example:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Hope that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

No that did not resolve the issue. But I saw another thread discussing the same issue and one of the answer there worked. I removed `<mvc:resources>` line from spring xml and added the below lines in the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now my static content is served without any issues but I don't like this method. It feels like a very dirty hack. Now if I have to serve images, I have to add mapping for each image type. I am not sure whether the spring version is a problem because I use mongodb in the backend with spring data. It took a hell of a time to set up my pom.xml because there were some issues with the spring data version and mongodb driver.